# Верю(,) что всё будет хорошо

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, спп

Нужна ли запятая после слова *верю* в указанном предложении?

```
вариант 1: Верю, что всё будет хорошо.
вариант 2: Верю что всё будет хорошо.
```

Вроде бы понятно, что решение зависит от того, каким членом предложения является слово *верю*. Сказуемым вводного предложения или вводным словом.

Посмотрел материалы статей, указанных моим оппонентом в данном споре, и ответа для себя не нашел. Точнее, мне кажется, что первая статья подтверждает, что после вводного предложения запятая нужна, и только.

1. [Запятые при вводных словах с распространением](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85_%D1%81_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/)
2. https://lifehacker.ru/zapyatye-ne-nuzhny/

Ещё один, как мне кажется, аналогичный пример.

```
Я знаю что все правильно сделал.
Я знаю, что всё правильно сделал.
```

Comment: В любом случае запятая ставится. Она ставится между частями сложного предложения.

Comment: Зависит от того, чем является "что". Я знаю что(делать), (теперь)всё будет хорошо! Но в ваших примерах запятая нужна.

Answer (score 1):

[Я] ***Верю, что** всё будет хорошо.

**Я знаю, что** всё правильно сделал.*

В этих сложноподчиненных предложениях **нет** вводных слов, а запятая перед союзом "что" ставится по общим правилам.
Сказуемые — *верю, знаю* (в первом предложении подлежащее "я" отсутствует, но подразумевается).

• *Сергею Анатольевичу я послал с книгой Потанина карты, 20 мексиканских долларов, чернил и прочие мелочи, но главным образом я послал китайскую грамоту. **Верю, что все будет хорошо!*** (П. К. Козлов).

Чаще всего в качестве вводных используются слова *веришь (ли), верите (ли), поверь, поверьте.*

Вот классическое предложение **с двумя** вводными словами:
***Видите,** я так люблю человечество, что, **верите ли,** мечтаю иногда бросить всё, всё, что имею, оставить Lise и идти в сестры милосердия* (Ф. Достоевский. Братья Карамазовы).

Вот еще:
***Поверьте,** я знаю себе цену: я знаю, как мало достоин я того, чтобы заменить вас в ее сердце* (И. Тургенев. Рудин).

[Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)